# bootstrap displaying is not perfect on my form

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have a little issue with a bootstrap form.

**Code**

```
<form class="<!-- form-horizontal --> form-inline text-left" id="form"  action="SubmitMainForm" method="post">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
        <label class=" col-xs-1" for="test1">test1</label>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
            <input class="form-control " type="text" name="test1" id="test1">
        </div>
        <label class=" col-xs-1" for="test2">test2</label>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
            <input class="form-control " type="text" name="test2" id="test2">
        </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
        <label for="description" class="col-xs-1">Description</label>
        <textarea class=" col-xs-11" rows="6" name="ta_description" id="ta_description"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
        <label for="description" class="col-xs-1">Description</label>
        <textarea class=" col-xs-5" rows="6" name="ta_description"  id="ta_description"></textarea>
        <label for="description" class="col-xs-1">Description</label>
        <textarea class=" col-xs-5" rows="6" name="ta_description"  id="ta_description"></textarea>
    </div>

    <!-- test with no div for the input control (not working) -->
    <!--  
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
        <label class=" col-xs-1" for="test1">test1</label>
        <input class="form-control col-xs-5" type="text" name="test1" id="test1">
        <label for="description" class="col-xs-1">Description</label>
        <textarea class=" col-xs-5" rows="6" name="ta_description"  id="ta_description"></textarea>
    </div>
    -->
</form>
```

As you can see, there's a little glitch on the first line.
The controls are not correctly alligned to the next lines controls.
I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.4.

How can I have this fixed to make it cute looking?

thx in advance.

Comment: please remove comment and value completely: <form class=" form-inline......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get the job done. Be sure to follow the documentation on the Bootstrap site. You can figure this out :)

Here's what I came up with for you. Compare this to what you currently have so you can see where you went wrong.

```
<div class="container">
<form class="form-horizontal" id="form" action="SubmitMainForm" method="post">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="test1">test1</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="test1" id="test1">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="test2">test2</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="test2" id="test2">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="description" class="control-label col-sm-2">Description</label>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10">
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="6" name="ta_description" id="ta_description"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="description" class="control-label col-sm-2">Description</label>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10">
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="6" name="ta_description" id="ta_description"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="description" class="control-label col-sm-2">Description</label>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10">
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="6" name="ta_description" id="ta_description"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Thanks to your code, I found out that what was missing in my code was a 
    <div class="row"> before the first controls line (containing the 2 input controls).
Thx again :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove comment in form class and use any one class name:
and I edit code just try

```
<form class="form-horizontal col-xs-offset-2" id="form"  action="SubmitMainForm" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class=" col-xs-1" for="test1">test1</label>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <input class="form-control " type="text" name="test1" id="test1">
        </div>
        <label class=" col-xs-1" for="test2">test2</label>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <input class="form-control " type="text" name="test2" id="test2">
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="description" class="col-xs-1">Description</label>
         <div class="col-xs-5">
        <textarea  rows="3" cols="30" name="ta_description" id="ta_description"></textarea>
         </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="description" class="col-xs-1">Description</label>
         <div class="col-xs-3">
        <textarea  rows="3" cols="30" name="ta_description"  id="ta_description"></textarea>
         </div>
        <label for="description" class="col-xs-1">Description</label>
         <div class="col-xs-3">
             <textarea rows="3" cols="30" name="ta_description"  id="ta_description"></textarea>
         </div>
    </div>

   </form>
```